# How do I call data from a div in a different div on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I am trying to create an online radio station. As part of the process, I need my player to call track/story data when the play button for a story is clicked on a different part of the page.

I'm using JSON to call the data to the each div. The data I have for stories is as follows:

```
<div class="play_button text-hide" 
data-id="{id}" 
data-title="{title}" 
data-storyurl="{fullUrl}" 
data-program="{category}" 
data-programurl="{category.fullUrl}" 
data-type="audio" 
data-src="{soundcloudLink}" 
data-item-type="story" 
data-pub-date="{addedOn}">
</div>
```

How would I call that data to my player, which is a separate div on click?

In other words, my page will have multiple stories with audio files, and whenever one of them is clicked, I would like the player to display

```
<div>
<a href="{fullUrl}">{title}</a>
<a href="{category.fullUrl}">{category}</a>
</div>
```

For each track/story that is clicked.

[WBEZ](https://www.wbez.org/) was used as an example.

Comment: Are you using anything else than `jQuery`?

Comment: Have you consider the use of JSON objects to store data? You may wish to check AngularJS framework for data binding as well.

Comment: You could use the `.attr()` function:

`$(this).attr('data-title')`
or if you lowercase the attribute name:

data-fulltext="This is a span element"
then you could use the .data() function:

`$(this).data('fulltext')`
The `.data` function expects and works only with lowercase attribute names

Comment: @FDavidov I am using JSON to call the data from the server. I am using angular to call soundcloud tracks. 

Would data-binding help me call whatever track is clicked on the page, to the player?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am using Angular to call tracks from Soundcloud and JSON. Would you recommend something different?

Comment: Angular's data binding is a powerful feature that enables you to have two-way link between HTML elements and JavaScript variables/objects. There are very many examples in the Web that can help you to understand its capabilities and benefits.This page gives quite good examples: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide your data by default and `onclick` you can set it to visible.

Try this,

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#panel, .flip {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: solid 1px #a6d8a8;
    margin: auto;
}

#panel {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="flip" onclick="myFunction()">Tere Sang yara</p>

<div id="panel">
  <p>Tere Sang yara</p>
  <p>Movie : Rushtam</p>
  <p>Great Movie</p>
  <p>Listening now</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("panel").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is on getting the data from the div and to the player this should do it:

```
$(".play_button").click(function(event){//click on the div with the information
    var el = $(this);//the div
    var dataToPass = {//your data in an object
        dataId: el.attr("data-id"), 
        dataTitle: el.attr("data-title"), 
        dataStoryUrl: el.attr("data-storyurl"), 
        dataProgram: el.attr("data-program"), 
        dataProgramUrl: el.attr("data-programurl"), 
        dataType: el.attr("data-type"), 
        dataSrc: el.attr("data-src"), 
        dataItemType: el.attr("data-pub-date")};

    //Send it to your player (not sure what your idea is)

    //You can access it like
    var test = dataToPass.dataId;//same goes for the others
});
```

---

Answering your comment:

If you have a class or an id on the target div, say `target`:

```
<div id = "target"> <a href="{data-storyurl}">{data-title}</a> <a href="{data-programurl}">{data-program}</a> </div>
```

,you can do:

```
    $("#target").html(
'<a href="'+dataToPass.dataStoryUrl+'">"'+dataToPass.dataTitle+'"</a>\
<a href="'+dataToPass.dataProgramUrl+'">"'+dataToPass.dataProgram+'"</a>');
```

*the `'\'` at the end of line 2 is just for the line break in the string*

---

**All together** now (I removed the unused variables (**attributes**) for this part):

```
$(".play_button").click(function(event){//click on the div with the information
    var el = $(this);//the clicked div
    var dataToPass = {//your data in an object
        dataTitle: el.attr("data-title"), 
        dataStoryUrl: el.attr("data-storyurl"), 
        dataProgram: el.attr("data-program"), 
        dataProgramUrl: el.attr("data-programurl")};

    //Send it to the target div
     $("#target").html(
'<a href="'+dataToPass.dataStoryUrl+'">"'+dataToPass.dataTitle+'"</a>\
<a href="'+dataToPass.dataProgramUrl+'">"'+dataToPass.dataProgram+'"</a>');
});
```

Comment: So if I wanted to send the code so that the result looked like this:

    `<div>
    <a href="{data-storyurl}">{data-title}</a>
    <a href="{data-programurl}">{data-program}</a>
    </div>`

How would I access it?

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much. 

As an aside, do you know if there is a similar way of accomplishing what your code did in AngularJS? 

I'm hoping I can figure it out. Also, need to work out some dependencies, like not displaying anything when the data is undefined. 

If nothing more, thanks again, as I am very grateful!